# Error while Running react-native app on ios simulator with npm start - Cannot read property 'resolver' of Undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am using Mac os Mojave10.14.6 and I  execute the following commands on terminal :

1. brew search node
2. brew install node@12 (since I read we need to
   install an older version of node, I tried with latest also but same
   result)
3. brew install npm
4. npm install npm i -g create-react-native-app
5. create-react-native-app my-project
6. cd my-project
7. npm start

The last command start building project and opens browser when I click on run on ios simulator I get this error

[image: Error]

Comment: create-react-native-app as it is not maintained anymore and I would suggest you to follow the route mentioned here. Use `expo-cli` - https://forums.expo.io/t/cannot-run-expo-start-error-cannot-read-property-resolver-of-undefined/28614

Comment: But I have seen many examples using the same command